# statistical test in R for normalized time course data

Tags: r, anova, growth-model

```
gene    time    average stdev
gene1   24h    1.1     0.01
gene1   48h    0.9     0.023
gene1   72h    0.7     0.01
gene1   96h    0.5     0.021
```

My data above shows the growth response of cells after altering gene1. I have normalized the growth againt a controls. What statiscical test should I use to show that the growth is significantly altered?